# why are these two different in abstract algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a nonempty set closed under an associative product,which in addition satisfies:

(1) There exists an $e\in G$ such that $a.e=a \forall a \in G$

(2)Give $a \in G$, there exists an element $y(a)\in G$ such that $a.y(a)=e$

Though it is a group under this product , why it can't be a group if we take

> $y(a).a=e$

in (2) instead? What are the differences ?

Comment: Do you know how to prove it's a group?

Comment: I know I am being very pedantic, but technically this definition is wrong/ambiguous, because the symbol $e$ in (2) is undefined. The whole of $(2)$ should be put within the scope of the sentence beginning "There exists .." in (1). It is ambiguous because there are two reasonable interpretations: does (2) hold for some $e$ satisfying (1) or for all such $e$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $S$ be a set with more than one element, select some particular $e$ in $S$ to be singled out as a right identity. Define for $x,y \in S$ that $x \cdot y=x.$ Then indeed $e$ works as a right identity element. But also given any $a$ we can use $y(a)=e$ and have $y(a) \cdot a=e \cdot a=e.$

But this set, with this operation, is not a group. To see why it isn't a group: consider two distinct elements $u,v$ of $S,$ and use that $e \cdot u = e \cdot v,$ by the way the product is defined both are $e.$ If this $S$ were actually a group one could cancel the $e$'s and get to $u=v.$

Comment: how is it possible that u,v are distinct still e.u=e.v,  Is there any example?

Comment: @mystak Read the description of "$\cdot$". It's defined so that $x\cdot y=x$ for all $x, y$; so in particular, $e\cdot u=e\cdot v=e$. (In fact, *every* element is a right identity in this structure.)

Comment: @mystak As Noah notes, in this (admittedly unusual) example, the product of any two $a,b$ is defined as being the first factor, that is, $ab=a$ for all $a,b.$ True this isn't a normal situation, but it *is* an associative product. When the set has more than one element, there is no two sided identity, so it isn't even a monoid. Guess it's just a semigroup. And in this semigroup, *any* element can be used as a right identity element, and once one of those is arbitrarily chosen to be $e,$ then for any $x,$ that chosen $e$ serves as a left inverse for $x.$

Answer (score 0):

Property 2 gives the existence of right inverses. Remember that not all operations are abelian. So this is different than having left inverses which is what you stated.

If the identity is both a left and right identity, then you have a group and what you stated is equivalent to Property 2.

[Monoid where every element is left-invertible equals group.](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Monoid_where_every_element_is_left-invertible_equals_group)